# Why does LAN stops working if switch is connected to two upfeeds?is

Tags: local-area-network, tcpip, troubleshooting, network-protocols

If I connect my switch to *two* upstream feeds from my ISP, my internal LAN stops functioning (see illustration below).

What is it in the TCP/IP protocol that is disrupted to cause the above?

```
                 +--------+
                 |        |
        +>>>>>>>>+        +>>>>>>>>>>> LAN machine 1 (not working normally)
        ^        |        +
ISP >>>>+        | switch +
        v        |        +
        +>>>>>>>>+        +>>>>>>>>>>> LAN machine 2 (not working normally)
                 |        |
                 +--------+
```

Comment: Install and run Wireshark, and I bet you'll find out a lot...

Comment: We miss a lot of info. VLAN or not? spanning-tree or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two scenario possible:

1. Configure the spanning-tree protocol please to prevent a network loop if both link send the same feed.
2. Configure the switch with some VLAN to isolate the LAN from the WAN.